# How to check if the post exists in any of the categories?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, posts, categories

What I am doing is, I have to check if the post exists in any of the categories or not.
I have tried below two codes but it's not working for me.

This is the first code

```
foreach ($scats as $key => $value) {
//echo $value->name;
if (is_object_in_term(get_the_ID(),$value->term_id)) {
echo "Found in category: " . esc_html($value->name);
        }
}
```

This is the second code

```
foreach ($scats as $category) {
    if (in_category($category->slug, get_the_ID())) {
        echo "Found in category: " . esc_html($category->name);
    }
}
```

I am not getting the output. Would you help me out with this?

Below is the `$scats` array

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 700
            [name] => Change
            [slug] => change
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 700
            [taxonomy] => solution_cats
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 6
            [filter] => raw
            [cat_ID] => 700
            [category_count] => 6
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => Change
            [category_nicename] => change
            [category_parent] => 0
        )

    [1] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 701
            [name] => Game
            [slug] => game
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 701
            [taxonomy] => solution_cats
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 9
            [filter] => raw
            [cat_ID] => 701
            [category_count] => 9
            [category_description] => 
            [cat_name] => Game
            [category_nicename] => game
            [category_parent] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: I could tell why the 1st code didn't work, but what is `$scats`, i.e. how are you getting the categories? Can you add the code to your post/question, and are you sure `get_the_ID()` is giving the correct post ID?

Comment: @SallyCJ, I have added the $scats code in the question. The first code shows all the category names and I want if the post exists in the category then show  that category . Yes, get_the_ID() is showing the correct Id number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are doing this for a **custom taxonomy** (`solution_cats`), then you should instead use [`has_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) and *not* [`in_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/) which works only with the default/core `category` taxonomy. So try this with your second code:

- `has_term( $category->slug, $category->taxonomy, get_the_ID() )`

[`is_object_in_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_object_in_term/) can also be used, but your syntax was not correct – the 2nd parameter is actually the term's taxonomy and not the term ID/name/slug (which should instead be the 3rd parameter).

- The correct syntax: `is_object_in_term(get_the_ID(),$value->taxonomy,$value->term_id)`
- But you used this: `is_object_in_term(get_the_ID(),$value->term_id)`

Comment: Oh Yes, it's perfect, Thank you so much.. Upvote from my side.